# How to print All possibilities or permutation in python?

Tags: python, permutation

I have this code

```
import random


Char = 'CDHKMPQRVXY123456789'
total = 10
count = 4

for i in range(total):
    unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(Char, count)) 
    print(unique_code)
```

how can i print all possibilities 'unique_code' with permutation sequentially?

output expectation like :

```
CDHK
CDHM
CDHP
CDHQ
CDHR
CDHV
CDHX
CDHY
CDH1
```

Print All the possibility Until all permutation done.
forget the random code that i wrote.

Comment: Please look for existing answers before asking something already asked a thousand times. [ask]

Comment: if i use that import, can i custom it?
ex:
when i print perms, output : ('M', 'K', '7') ('M', 'K', '8') but how can i print like (MK7) (MK8)?

Comment: the answer is in your own post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `itertools.permutations` function

As a side note, consider using `secrets` instead of `random`; the `random` module is for simulations, generating a code should use `secrets`. The interfaces are the same.